# How to not use threads

Tags: dart, stagexl

This is a dart newbie question about how to do "multithreading" in dart.

(Excuse me I am an old java developer ...)

So I have this kind of code (se below) but since recreating the gui is costly I would like to defer it so that instead of recreating the gui in the _onWindowResize() I would like to start a thread that does this when the size has been stable some time. E.g. for one second.

If a thread is already is started do nothing. (Btw, StageXL is cool ....)

(This will also fix the bug that _onWindowResize() is called twice by the dart:html ...)

```dart
   ...
  html.window.onResize.listen((e) => _onWindowResize());
}

_createGui() {
  var shape = new Shape();
  shape.graphics.ellipse(html.window.innerWidth / 2, html.window.innerHeight / 2, html.window.innerWidth / 4, html.window.innerHeight / 4);
  shape.graphics.fillColor(Color.Red);
  stage.addChild(shape);
}

void _onWindowResize() {
  print("New window size ${html.window.innerWidth}x${html.window.innerHeight}");

  stage = new Stage('stage', canvas);
  stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
  stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

  renderLoop = new RenderLoop();
  renderLoop.addStage(stage);
  juggler = renderLoop.juggler;

  _createGui();
}
```

Comment: Note: This is a bad example since I found out that stagexl does this for me more or less ... but anyhow the question is generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can send work to other threads in Dart via [Isolates](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate.html), but this won't work for your scenario since it's mostly about modifying the UI of the app.

One cannot share objects between isolates in Dart (or using WebWorkers in general). So you cannot pass the canvas into an Isolate to create your stage, renderloop, etc.

If you are doing complex calculations (Physics, for example), it might make sense to send those off to an Isolate and use the result to update the UI.